# fn instanceof Function VS Object.prototype.toString.call(fn) === "[object Function]"

Tags: javascript, function

I see a lot of pros javascript developer testing if an object is a function using

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(fn) === "[object Function]"
```

Usually I am using

```
fn instanceof Function === true
```

can someone enlighten me. Thank you

Comment: Use neither. Always do `typeof fn == 'function'`!

Comment: For me your actual question was hard to get out of the title. Maybe you could change it to something like 'What is the best way to check if a javascript object is a function'

Comment: @EimerReis From the body of his question I assume he specifically meant the difference between `Object.prototype.toString.call` and `instance of`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`instanceof` just looks for the `constructor` property in the prototype chain. See [the standard](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-instanceofoperator):

> [`@@hasInstance`](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-well-known-symbols): A method that determines if a constructor object recognizes an object as one of the constructor's instances. Called by the semantics of the instanceof operator.

Which means you can "trick" it:

```js
let Constructor = function(){};
Constructor.prototype = Function.prototype;

let Not_A_Real_Function = function(){};
Not_A_Real_Function.prototype = new Constructor;

let not_a_real_function = new Not_A_Real_Function;

// instanceof
console.log(not_a_real_function instanceof Function); 
// prints true

// Object.prototype.toString
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(not_a_real_function) === "[object Function]");
// prints false

// typeof
console.log(typeof not_a_real_function === "function");
// prints false
```

A downside of `Object.prototype.toString` however is that you can potentially override it all together, to make it return whatever you want.

```js
let Object = {
    prototype: {
        toString(fn){
            return "foo";
        }
    }
};

let fc = function(){};
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(fc) === "foo");
```

---

For the sake of completeness: 
As [@Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) pointed out,

```js
typeof fn == "function"
```

is probably the safest way. (See the first snippet)

Comment: Thank you. but not_a_real_function is an object we should perhaps combined it with typeof fn === 'function' to be sure..

Comment: @pablopento I added it to the snippet if that's what you meant

Comment: Apart from being able to trick them intentionally, I was mainly concerned with them not working in cross-frame environments or with a `async function() {}` or `function*() {}`.